# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, regex, regexextract

I am trying to make a certain cell on my sheet light up based on what week it is.

Each cell contains the value `Week X` where the `X` is a week-number.

After a little bit of experimentation I have made the following:
[image]

Here the cells `A4:A56` are the cells with `Week X` in them.

I want each one each week to light up in beautiful yellow based on the week, but instead, this does nothing (no cells turn yellow).

Is there any way I can get my desired result with conditional formatting in Google Sheets?

Update (an attempted answer made by Rubén, did not work):

[image]

Comment: Add sample data to the question and a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link can view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A4,"\d+"))=WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To use a formula for conditional formatting, instead of `Text ends with` select `Custom Formula`.

Then use a formula like the following

```
=RIGHT(A4,1)=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())
```

Comment: I attempted your solution but no change was made to any cells, sadly. Did I make a mistake?